# Explicit type casting in C++

Tags: c++, casting, void-pointers, explicit-conversion

I am trying to convert a `C` code to `C++`. In my .c file I've definitions like this:

```
void services(void);
void transfers(void);
```

Further more, a thread will initialize the above two like this:

```
_beginthread((void*) services,0,NULL);
_beginthread((void*) transfers,0,NULL);
```

When I try to compile, I got the following error at both the places above like this:

```
Conversion from void* to pointer to non-void required an Explicit cast: Cannot convert parameter 1 from void* to void(_cdecl*)(void*)
```

I am confused about this, hope you guys make it clear for me :-)

Comment: you can simply use `extern "C"` linkage and leave your C code alone

Comment: According to the `_beginthread` documentation on MSDN, the parameter for the thread routine is a `void *` not a `void`. Perhaps C is more forgiving about that.

Comment: What is the signature for _beginthread function?

Comment: Just a passing comment: type casts are **always** explicit. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. When you write a cast, the **conversion** is explicit; when the compiler does a conversion without a cast the conversion is implicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
_beginthread((void(_cdecl*)(void*)) services, 0, NULL);
```

What you were doing was explicitly casting the function pointer to a non-function pointer type (`void *`).  This was OK.  But the `_beginthread` function expects as its first parameter a function pointer of the correct type mentioned in the error message.  So you need to fix your cast.

---

If you're about to downvote this answer, I'd appreciate to know the reason why.  I know it would be much better if user2754070 wanted to change the prototype of `services` (see my comments below).  However, what I'm suggesting works (the answer was accepted) and, as far as I know, it is safe and standard practice in C libraries spawning threads.  If you think it's not, please explain why and I'll consider deleting the answer.

Comment: Casting a function is a terrible idea, you're likely to leave the call stack in a corrupt state.

Comment: @molbdnilo, please explain and provide an answer.  Passing generic function pointers to functions like `_beginthread`, `pthread_create` etc. is standard procedure and may involve type casting.  I don't understand why this is not safe.

Comment: @molbdnilo, your answer is right (and +1) but say, for the sake of an argument, that you cannot change the prototype for `services`.  What's wrong with what I'm suggesting?

Comment: One technical reason is that if the called function gets passed too few arguments, "funny" things will happen.

Comment: @molbdnilo, I understand that casting function pointers in general is a bad thing.  But for this particular case, there's no way to pass fewer parameters to `services`, as it expects none.  In fact, it will be called with one parameter (`NULL`), which will be handled OK (it has to, for backwards compatibility with a lot of horrible C code that exists out there).  So let's talk about this case; is this casting bad?

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to use functions of the correct type and *not* cast them. Ignore the parameter if it's not relevant to the code.

```
void services(void*);
void transfers(void*);

_beginthread(services, 0, NULL);
_beginthread(transfers, 0, NULL);
```

If you absolutely can't change the functions, e.g. if you don't have access to the sources, use wrappers:

```
void correct_services(void*) { services(); }
_beginthread(correct_services, 0, NULL);
```

The compiler is helping you here - don't try to work around it by lying to it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to convert from C++ calling standard to C calling standard. cdecl stands for C declaration.
To manually define a function to be cdecl you can use `void _cdecl funct();`